# Shadow from unknown source on my object

Tags: texturing, shadows

I'm new to Blender and still trying to figure a lot of stuff out.

I wanted to make some cloudy miso soup, so I added a noisy image texture to the soup object. There's a curved shadow on the soup that isn't produced by either of the lights (one overhead, one above and behind the viewer).

What might be causing this?

[image: Render output showing shadow on soup][image: A clearer view of the shadow]

[image]

Comment: provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: hard to know if we can't check the material you've used

Comment: In playing with your lights, it appears to be the light behind (Spot.001) that causes the shadow.  If I remove it or move it further overhead the shadow changes/disappears.  So it is a shadow cast from the front of the bowl lip into the back rear. Set you soup material Transmission to 1 (from your 0.407) to exaggerate the effect as you adjust the light.